Run Python coroutine functions concurrently, but start additional coroutines as soon as particular coroutines have completed
I have four total coroutines (async def functions): A, B, C, and D. C can't be called until I know the result of A, and D can't be called until I know the result of A and B. See the attached diagram. I want to run these coroutines concurrently such that the total time spent until I get the results from C and D is minimized.

We should start by running A and B concurrently, but I it would be sub-optimal to use a, b = asyncio.gather(get_a(), get_b()) because C should be started as soon as A finishes, and doesn't need to wait around for B to complete.
Similarly, we could run A and C in sequence, while also running B concurrently (as shown below) but in this case we might be waiting around to start D longer than needed if A and B have completed but C is still running:
async def group_1():
    a = await get_a()
    c = await get_c(a)
    return c

c, b = asyncio.gather(
    group_1(),
    get_b(),
)

How can I execute these tasks without any unnecessary waiting?
I imagine I could use callbacks if necessary, but I would prefer to use a higher level construct if possible. Additionally, my actual use case has more tasks than this with more complex dependency chains, and I think callbacks would quickly become difficult to reason about.

You've asked for "higher level construct", I tried something.
part 1: a scheduler with jobs defined by (name, coroutine, dependency1, dep2, ...). It keeps track of coroutines done and starts only jobs with satisfied dependencies. A taskgroups makes sure it will run all coroutines till end (or till the first error).
import asyncio
import functools

class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self, *jobs):
        self._todo = {name: (coro, set(deps)) for name, coro, *deps in jobs}
        self._done = set()
        self._wakeup = asyncio.Event()

    def _task_done(self, name, _task):
        print(f"debug: done: {name}")
        self._done.add(name)
        self._wakeup.set()

    async def run(self):
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg: 
            while self._todo:
                to_start = [ 
                    (name, coro) for name, (coro, deps) in self._todo.items()
                    if deps <= self._done]  # set subset test
                for name, coro in to_start:
                    print(f"debug: start: {name}")
                    task = tg.create_task(coro())
                    task.add_done_callback(functools.partial(self._task_done, name))
                    del self._todo[name]
                await self._wakeup.wait()
                self._wakeup.clear()

part 2: a demo
async def coro_a():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    
async def coro_b():
    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
    
async def coro_c():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def coro_d():
    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)

async def main():
    sch = Scheduler(
        ('A', coro_a),
        ('B', coro_b),
        ('C', coro_c, 'A'),
        ('D', coro_d, 'A', 'B'),
    )
    await sch.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


OP here. I think I've come up with a solution for this problem, which is to use asyncio.create_task() to start A and B in the background. C and D can then both await the A task (full example below). I'm still not certain if this is the cleanest way to do it though, so additional answers are still welcome.
import asyncio
async def get_a():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return "a"

async def get_b():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return "b"
    
async def get_c(a):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return "c"
    
async def get_d(a, b):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return "d"

async def main():
    a_task = asyncio.create_task(get_a())
    b_task = asyncio.create_task(get_b())
    
    async def c_wrapper():
        a = await a_task
        return await get_c(a)
    
    async def d_wrapper():
        a = await a_task
        b = await b_task
        return await get_d(a, b)
    
    return await asyncio.gather(c_wrapper(), d_wrapper())

asyncio.run(main())


Note that my answer is conceptually very similar to the one posted by Pwnosaurus, which I have upvoted, but I believe it expresses the dependencies in a slightly cleaner and more reusable way:
Since calling get_c can only occur after get_a returns a value (and likewise with get_d and get_b), I think the simplest approach without designing a dependency scheduler is to just create two new coroutines get_a_c and get_b_d that encapsulate the dependencies:
import asyncio
import time

async def get_a():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 7

async def get_b():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return 9

async def get_c(a):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return a ** 2

async def get_d(a, b):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return a ** 2 + b ** 3

async def get_a_c():
    a = await get_a()
    return await get_c(a)

async def get_a_b_d():
    a, b = await asyncio.gather(get_a(), get_b())
    return await get_d(a, b)

async def main():
    t = time.monotonic()
    results = await asyncio.gather(get_a_c(), get_a_b_d())
    elapsed = time.monotonic() - t
    print(results, elapsed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Prints:
[49, 778] 2.0160000000032596


Thanks for providing an answer, however get_d() needs to depend on a as well as b. In your solution b is the only dependency for d.

Sorry about that -- I have updated the answer.
